# Define base URL for HTML/CSS path completion

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete

As far as I can tell from the [tests for HTML path completion](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/44460) when the feature was added in 2018, path completion always uses the workspace root as the base URL for paths beginning with `/`; note under *Verify* it says:

> - / shows file/folders from workspace root (test on multi root too)

This is often not very practical, though, because absolute HTML/CSS paths by definition start from the *website’s document root*, which is frequently not the same as the VSCode workspace’s root. For instance, in workspaces that are structured according to [many common MVC patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7960483/1302127), path completion will not work for absolute paths since, within the workspace, the path it should start from is really `/public` (or `/web` or whatever), not `/`.

I can’t find any settings in VSCode that relate to HTML/CSS path completion (`html.completion.attributeDefaultValue` is the closest, and that’s [something else entirely](https://code2020.dev/html-attribute-default-value/)). I haven’t even been able to find an extension that provides this functionality.

**Is there a way to specify a path within the workspace that should be used as the base URL for HTML/CSS path completions?**